# How Create Nested table from an existing table using select statement in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have to create a nested table with repeated columns in BigQuery by selecting them from an input table.

I have sample input data looks like this,

```
v1  ITPK8   E97
v1  PNLGVO  152
v2  SCDVOL  A55
v1  DA      38
v3  RES35   848
v2  ITPK4   E97
v3  SSFAP   622
```

And the expected should be

```
v1  ITPK8   E97
    PNLGVO  152
    DA      38
v2  SCDVOL  A55
    ITPK4   E97
v3  RES35   848
    SSFAP   622
```

Please let me know the generic BigQuery to achieve this? I have a lot of data present in the input table hence I require Generic query please.

I have tried with below query but no luck. Output data is not generated as expected.

```
create table `project.db.table_tgt` as 
select v_num, [STRUCT<obj1 STRING, obj2 STRING> (obj1, obj2)] as object 
from `project.db.table_src` order by v_num
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing:

```
create table `project.db.table_tgt` as 
select v_num, array_agg(STRUCT(obj1, obj2)) as object 
from `project.db.table_src` group by v_num order by v_num
```

Comment: Hi @rmesteves, it's working with your query. Thanks a lot.